# TileStache Internal Server Error

Tags: mapnik, tilemill, tilestache

I was installing TileStache and and followed all the necessary steps, Upon running the *tilestache-server.py* file, It starts the server at *http://127.0.0.1:8080/*. And opening this into my browser gives the message **'TileStache bellows hello'** which is okay. But when I try to run the url for osm basemap layer which is *http://localhost:8080/osm/0/0/0.png* it always gives me an error message saying **"Internal Server Error"**.

I have tried installing different TileStache versions but the issue is same with every version I install. I am not sure about the reasons that are causing this issue.

Screenshot of the error shared below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default OSM tiles are created using live URL of OSM which is mentioned in the default configuration file of Tilestache. There is a possibility that you have limited network access, Due to which python cannot get response through urllib2 from live URL. 
You need to test this in the following ways:

1. Change your network then run Tilestache server and test it on OSM layer.
2. Create a new style for an offline layer using Tilemill, add it to the tilestache configuration file and run server to test on the new layer.

Comment: The network change solved the problem. Thankyou!